# Can't login after proxypass

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, proxypass

I have setup an apache server as reverse proxy to point 2 different DNS names to correct servers. One of them works great, it is a simple web page with some pages.

The other one doesn't, it is a more complicated system which requires users to login first. The problem with this page started as to reach it I need to get to "10.105.27.230/app". Without /app It doesn't work. The thing is that this app installed apache itself and it isn't found under /var/www/ folder, but in other place.

Right now I can get to the page, but when I try to login example.com, it just redirects me to example.com/app and shows the same login page. I think its something to do with my proxypass, but can't find the right configuration as it is my first time working with proxies.

At first, as I tried to setup reverse proxy (proxy server), the page worked but without css and images.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName example.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://10.105.27.230/app/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.105.27.230/app/
</VirtualHost>
```

I searched for solutions and think I fixed it with another proxypass before the original one. After this the page works with css and images, but after I login it redirects to example.com/app.

```
    ProxyPass /app http://10.105.27.230/app/
    ProxyPassReverse /app http://10.105.27.230/app/
    ProxyPass / http://10.105.27.230/app/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.105.27.230/app/
```

If I go directly to the http://10.105.27.230/app/ I can login and after login it shows this link http://10.105.27.230/app/#/home. And the link changes only after /#/.

How can I get it to work correctly so that I can login and work with the system from the example.com?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The problem was, that

1. I was testing an application without TLS (just a rough run on good old HTTP).
2. I was running more apps on the proxy server and had a global setting for making cookies Secure.

What happened was, that the cookies were stripped (parameter Secure means do not send cookies over HTTP, only send them over HTTPS). The Application server created them, but they have never made it to the web browser.
A quick solution to not compromise other apps was to dit the header only for the testing app, so under the "proxy virtual host". I have added:

```
Header edit* Set-Cookie "(session=.*)(;Secure)" "$1"
```

I have never used any app without TLS, even in testing. So this took me some time to crack.